# Kineticjs to small image

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have this simple code and I want to set the minimum width and the minimum height of the image, I set min. height and min. width, and when it comes to these limits, the tag off as I want, but when I click on the image, tag appears in a different place and I can not enlarge my photos..

```
if (width && height) {
    if (MIN_WIDTH < width || MIN_HEIGHT < height) {
        image.setSize(width, height);
    } else {
        group.children[1].hide();
        group.children[2].hide();
        group.children[3].hide();
        group.children[4].hide();
        $(".toSmall").dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 350,
            height: 180,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    image.setSize(image.width, image.height);
                    console.log(activeAnchor.attrs.draggable = false);
                    activeAnchor.attrs.x *= 2;
                    activeAnchor.attrs.y *= 2;
                    image.off('click');
                    // activeAnchor.setDragOnTop(false);
                    // activeStage.draw();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution

```
if (width && height) {
    if (MIN_WIDTH < width || MIN_HEIGHT < height) {
        image.setSize(width, height);
    } else {
        $(".toSmall").dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 350,
            height: 180,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                    activeAnchor.hide();
                    activeAnchor.attrs.y *= 2;
                    image.off('click');
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    update(activeAnchor);
                    activeStage.draw();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```